# How on earth do I get react to actually work on a web server - just keep getting loads of errors - mainly from Babel

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I've been playing with react for a while now and it seems quite good.  I managed to get React working on my home computer easily enough using NPM to install it and then running npm start and it seems to work.

However if I upload the files it created with npm to my webhost (ecohosting) all I seem to get is some message about "require is not defined" in the console.  I've tried searching for the answer and all I get is something about having to change the module settings.

I've also tried creating my own stand alone version of react just using a load of CDN links to both babel and react and am getting the same response.

This is my code I've tried :-

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>

<script>
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
    </div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        const test = (
            <h1>
                This test works
            </h1>
        );
        ReactDOM.render(test, document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't believe I started playing with React thinking it looked quite exciting and new - but I can't find any clear instructions on how to actually set the thing up to render.  I normally use PHP and jQuery but thought I'd give React a go but so far it seems too overly complicated to get it working, more than jQuery or even PHP (jQuery you just add the jQuery CDN and you're done - with this React you need all this extra Babel included and the instructions for doing this on anything other than your home computer seems extremely vague).  Am I just missing something really stupidly simple here or is React only designed for things like web apps and not for HTML use??

Do I need to do something with npm like build it before uploading or do I need to run start from something like the web hosts CLI (which my web host doesn't give me access to SSH).

Comment: can you attach screenshot please

Answer (score 0):

I am also PHP developer who landed up with react so i understand the confusion. As you correctly guessed we need to first build the project and then upload that to the server. React is mainly used to create Single Page applications. If you want to play around with React you could use Create React App which includes all these configurations. Then use services like netlify and vercel for easy deployments.

To be perfectly honest i havent used the CDN approach so not sure about that part

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yeah I thought I might have to build it first - I was playing around a bit with it also in codecademy and they seemed to have a system that would work immediately straight from the website - that's why I thought there was some CDN way of doing it but clearly there isn't.  If it can't be converted automatically in the web browser then I guess that kind of destroys the reason I was going to use it in the first place and until web browsers actually produce their own JSX decoder I might as well just carry on getting PHP to generate HTML.